# How do I run a Python Qt file in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, qt, ubuntu, pyqt

Here's the sample code that I want to run:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 300)
window.setWindowTitle("Dummy PyQt file")

window.show()
```

The file is saved as `sample.py`. The following command isn't working:

```
$ python ./sample.py
```

Comment: Whats is the error ?

Comment: There are no errors. But there is no output either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the Qt event loop by calling `app.exec_()` once you have initialised the widgets and called `show()` on your main window.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 300)
window.setWindowTitle("Dummy PyQt file")
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`app.exec_()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec) to start the [`Qt` event loop](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects#Events_and_the_event_loop). Without it the program exits immediately before anything can be shown on screen.